# Initialize and store N instances of an object in a let constant array?

Tags: arrays, swift, initialization, constants

I want to initialize and store N copies of the same object in an immutable array so that the array length cannot change and the objects cannot be overwritten.

I tried using the `init(repeating:count:)` function of `Array`, but it appears to make an array with `count` references to the `repeating` argument if the `repeating` argument is not a primitive.

The playground code below illustrates the problem:

```
class Thing { }

let tenThings : [Thing] = Array(repeating: Thing(), count: 10)

if (tenThings[0] === tenThings[1]) {
    print("tenThings stores 10 references to the same Thing.")
} else {
    print("tenThings stores 10 references to 10 different Things")
}
> tenThings stores 10 references to the same Thing.
```

I want `tenThings` to store the same result as this:

`let tenMoreThings: [Thing] = [Thing(), Thing(), Thing(), Thing(), Thing(), Thing(), Thing(), Thing(), Thing(), Thing()]`

I guess I could append to a temporary array with a loop and assign it to the the let constant array, but I'm hoping for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is this?:

```
class Thing { }

let tenThings : [Thing] = (0..<10).map{_ in Thing()}
```